# What are the ways that we can automate many mobile tests case in many devices?

Tags: appium, multi-device-hybrid-apps, aws-device-farm

I'm automating my tests via Appium. I want to test on multiple devices.

I know about AWS Device Farm and Test Object, which one do you recommand for me in order to test the same tests on many devices.

Do you recommand other tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Device Farm gives you the ability to test on multiple devices at the same time.

**Things to think about:**

**Automated testing:**

1. For automated testing, Device farm support a variety of test frameworks like Appium, Calabash, Espresso, XCUI Test, UI Automation and UI Automator.
2. Device Farm also has support for continuous integration via Jenkins and gradle plugins.
3. The device list is up to date and you get access to the latest devices as soon as they are released.
4. You also get access to devices based on carrier versions.
5. Test reporting is a neat feature which helps you figure out unique problems, gives instant access to all logs and the ability to filter through them intelligently.
6. They also give a video recording  of your entire test.

**Manual testing**

1. They provide remote access capability using which you can interact with the device in a browser. This is very useful for manual testing where you want to play with an app and get the feel of the behavior on a particular device.
2. You can install apps on the fly.
3. The internet access of the device in unrestricted.
4. They have an option of unlimited usage.

**Device type**
You have the option of choosing the public fleet devices which are shared and private devices where the devices will be dedicated and used exclusively by you. Private devices can be useful if you have specific configuration needed before testing or have specific security requirements. The other advantage is reliable availability of the devices.

Hope that helps.